# Read aloud data from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am looking for a way to read data from a JTable out loud, in order to comply with the Americans With Disabilities Act.

I have researched using the Java Access Bridge, and that works for most Swing Components, but I cannot seem to find a solution that works with the contents of a JTable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you'er looking for something like [How to Support Assistive Technologies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/access.html)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource (e.g. library, tool) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. ([help/on-topic]) Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.